# How to limit "onListItemClick" to Time Range?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I Have One [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) in My Project and that List Show Data from Database (sqlite).

```
public void refreshDisplay() {
    ArrayAdapter<MyStory> adapter = new StoryAdapter(this, story);
setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and onListItemClick code:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    MyStory story = stories.get(position);

    Intent next = new Intent(this, ShowStory.class);
    next.putExtra("thisstory", story);
    startActivity(next);
}
```

Now, can i set enable/disable ListView Item only in the specific dates? for example one Story only readable (clickable) if system date is (for ex.) 29 June 2014?. 

Is there a need to add a Date column in the Database for each Story?

MainActivity Complete code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
DBAdapter db;
List<MyStory> stories;
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    list = getListView();
    db = new DBAdapter(getBaseContext());
    db.open();
    stories = db.getAllContacts();

    if (stories.size() == 0) {

        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases";

        try {
            CopyDB(getBaseContext().getAssets().open("StoryDB"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath + "/stories"));
            Log.i(DBAdapter.TAG, "DB Copy-OK");

            stories = db.getAllContacts();

        refreshDisplay(); 
            Log.i(DBAdapter.TAG, storiess.size() + "= stories count");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        refreshDisplay();
    }



@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Mystory story = stories.get(position);

    Intent next = new Intent(this, ShowStory.class);
    next.putExtra("thisstory", story);
    startActivity(next);
}


public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    // ---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}



public void refreshDisplay() {
    Log.i(DBAdapter.TAG, stories.size() + "= storeis count");

    ArrayAdapter<MyStory> adapter = new StoryAdapter(this, stories);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Is there a need to add a Date column in the Database for each Story? yes. Otherwise how will you compare

Comment: Thank yor answer. So how can i do it? I'm Really confused! @TerrilThomas

Comment: Whenever you add a story take the system time referenced to it and save it in the database

Comment: Can you write an example for one item? @TerrilThomas

Comment: I can simply guide you in this .Rather than feed you with the code.

Comment: What mean "Rather than feed you with the code."?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do compare the date inside onItemClick

```
  @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
if(Date compare)
{
 // do nothing
}
else
{
MyStory story = stories.get(position);

Intent next = new Intent(this, ShowStory.class);
next.putExtra("thisstory", story);
startActivity(next);
}
}
```

Comment: is this method for all items in the listview?

Comment: yup.. but before you have compare the current date with your database date

Comment: Can you write an example for one item? @Karthick Pandiyan